# Python Reverse Loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, python-3.8

```
name = "Hello World and Good Morning"
letnum = ""
for let in name:
 if let.isdigit() == False:
     letnum += let
     print(letnum)
```

I am trying to find a way to reverse this loop. I want it to start with the word fully spelled and then end with one letter left.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: it lets an integer go from the full string length down to 1, and displays each time that many characters of the original string:

```
name = "Hello World and Good Morning"
for length in range(len(name), 0, -1):
    if not name[length - 1].isdigit():
        print(name[:length])
```